# Attributes.Add() not working in asp.net

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I have added a CSS through code behind in asp.net on page_load. It works fine in my local environment but doesn't works on the server. Please see the code for your reference.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedValue = Request.QueryString["selectedValue"];
    updateCareer.Attributes.Add("style", "word-break:break-all; word-wrap:break-word");
    errordiv.InnerHtml = "";
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        rep_Jobs.DataBind();
    }
}
```

I am getting this below mentioned error:-

```
'System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel' does not contain a definition for 'Attributes' and no extension method 
'Attributes' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel' could be found (are you
 missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Let me know why this is happening. I haved added all the namespace related to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely your application is running on different versions of the .NET framework. Check out the [UpdatePanel.Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.attributes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page and you'll see that this property was introduced only in .NET 4, so versions below that will produce the error you are facing.

To have a cross-version solution you might have some container, say Panel, inside update panel which CSS you could update. Or update server version of .NET if it's possible.

Comment: Just what I was about to say. :)

Comment: @Andrei: So i am adding a panel inside that. Will it not effect other things, i guess ?

Comment: @Shrutika, it might affect you markup and styling. Just make sure to check that you app looks the same after you added that panel

Comment: OK, will look into the styling. I have a Content template inside update panel, so where should I add the panel ?

Comment: @Shrutika, just inside the content template, so that everything is wrapped with this panel. Also note that since this is a template, you won't be able to access the panel directly by ID in codebehind. Instead use something like `((Panel)updateCareer.FindControl("PanelIDHere"))`

Comment: I added that panel in aspx as u mentioned, but i am unable to call the ID in code behind. Also i have to give styling to it.

Comment: @Shrutika, that's exactly what I mean - use FindControl, since this panel is in template

Comment: Its still not working, I added as stated by you, I think i need to call updatePanel first then the panel. can u help please ?

Comment: @Shrutika, have you tried the way I have posted above, `((Panel)updateCareer.FindControl("PanelIDHere"))`?